# XSLT Issue appending to the last certain element

Tags: xslt

I can match on clause or p element but my requirement is in the output xml the last ei (&&&) in the tag should be appended to the last p element i.e **some p5 text &&&.** should be the output.

```
<clause>
  <ei>$$$</ei>
   <p>some p1 text</p>
   <p>some p2 text</p>
    <clause2>   
       <p>some p3 text</p>
       <p>some p4 text</p>
        ... 
        ...
       <p>some p5 text</p>
    </clause2>  
  <ei>&&&</ei>
</clause>
```

Comment: I don't see any XSLT, so your issue cannot be resolved due to a lack of input.

Comment: @Jongware actually i am looking for XSLT code this is just an xml. I need an xslt template that could match on either clause/p and append the last ei value in the element to the last p element.Hope this helps.

Comment: @user3496151 "*i am looking for XSLT code*" is not a question. Where exactly are you having a problem with this?

Comment: It does indeed help. Without you showing any effort, this is just a work order.

Comment: ok.. i tried a lot and was not successful. Anyways i will post the snippet that i have tried here

Comment: Please read [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and review how you're asking questions and [**accepting**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) answers.   *4 accepts out of 29 questions looks amiss.*

Answer (score 0):

Use this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                extension-element-prefixes="fn str">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>                                                                                                                                    

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="clause2[last()]/p[last()]">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/clause/ei[last()]/node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/clause/ei[last()]">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Test: http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9H/2

Comment: I suggest you learn about `xsl:copy` in general and the *identity transform* template in particular - as well as the built-in templates. That should cut your code to about half.

Comment: Counting lines is not the most important metric. Still, http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9H/5

Comment: O @michael.hor257k you've dropped a lot of functionality by converting {apply-template + copy-of} into {concat}. It doesn't effect on result for current input but it doesn't copy sub-nodes and attributes. Anyway, thanks;